# Passing props in react without rendering anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

First of all, does it make sense to do this?

Secondly I'll explain why I am thinking of doing this.

I have a component where I get the user to click 1 of 2 options. either yes or no.
They either get added to the yesArray or noArray. This component is called `Decision`.

Once they click Yes or No then I render the `Thanks` component. I want the arrays of people who said yes and the arrays of people who said no to be shown on this thanks page.

The problem is the logic to make the arrays is in `Decision` but I want it to be shown on `Thanks` but if I pass a prop down like this from the `Decision` component:

```
<Thanks
   showYesArray={this.state.yesArray}
/>
```

Then this will render the `<Thanks />` component whenever `<Decision />` is rendered but in my parent component `<Thanks />` should only be rendered when it is triggered by a state change and this can be different to when `<Decision />` is rendered

Can post more code if necessary and explain more too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state should be in a container element that holds both the Thanks and Decision Element.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Decision
      onYes={this.handleYes}
      onNo={this.handleNo}
    />

    <Thanks
      active={this.state.thanksActive}
      yesArray={this.state.yesArray}
      noArray={this.state.noArray}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: and then how would I pass the array from the function in Decision to <Thanks />??

Comment: The array would live in the container's state.

Comment: You setState in the handle functions.  Then you render that state in your Thanks component.

Comment: so I would have to remove all the logic into my main parent component and then pass it down as props accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use flag like `state.decision`, initially `false`, set it to `true` when yes/no is clicked, and render `Thanks` component only if it's `true`.

```
{this.state.decision && <Thanks showYesArray={this.state.yesArray} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use shouldComponentUpdate() and return false when update’s not needed. But more code could be very helpful to see what exactly you meant.